# Creating an observable from a subscribable?

Tags: rxjs

I have a non rxjs reactivity helper which has a `.subscribe()` method on it. It matches the `rxjs.Subscribable` interface but doesn't belong to rxjs.

Is there a utility in rxjs to wrap an observable-like object and produce an observable?

```
const nonRxjsSource$ = new NotObserable()

const rxSource$ = rxjs.fromSubscribable(nonRxjsSource$)
rxSource$.pipe(....)
```

Comment: You can use `from` that can handle multiple different inputs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts

Answer (score 1):

if it has the same subscribable interface you can create `Subject` to redirect.

```
const rxSource=new Subject();
nonRxjsSource$.subscribe(rxSource)
```